# Where is the ruby documentation for gems?

Tags: ruby, faraday

In python in an interactive console like ipython i can just type ? and get documentation on pretty much any library or function.

How do I do this in ruby? Whether I'm using pry or irb I can't find much useful documentation at all.

I'm trying to use Faraday but typing ri Faraday doesn't give any documentation. Typing ri String gives documentation for String, but gems like faraday don't produce any documentation whatsoever.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Bit confused as to how a question about problems installing ruby documentation is off-topic for a programming site... I'm not asking anyone to recommend anything, I'm asking why my ruby documentation seemed to not be working and thanks to the comments below I was able to sort my problem out...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you install the gem using `gem install --ri faraday` then the ri documentation will be generated for you.

This should be the default, but since Ri doc generation can take a while, a lot of people disable it by putting a line in `~/.gemrc` saying `gem: --no-ri --no-rdoc` (providing those options as defaults for the gem command).

Even if that's the case you can override it on a case by case basis by adding that parameter when you install a gem

Comment: This was the problem, `gem: --no-ri --no-rdoc` was in my `~/.gemrc`

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [pry-doc](https://rubygems.org/gems/pry-doc) extension for `pry`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to read that doc, You'll are able to run

```
gem server
```

That will create a webservice in you host on port 8808, that you will be able to access via browser.

If you want to see where that info is located, run *gem env* you'll see all  paths into GEM PATHS section.

gem env

```
RubyGems Environment:
.......2.2.2/etc
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    .....
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /home/hbranciforte/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2
     - /home/hbranciforte/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@global
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     .....
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
.....
```

and if you look at your GEM PATHS you will find a folder called doc.

```
hbranciforte@hbranciforte-MacBookPro:gems/ruby-2.2.2 $ cd /home/hbranciforte/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2
hbranciforte@hbranciforte-MacBookPro:gems/ruby-2.2.2 $ ls
bin  build_info  cache  doc  environment  extensions  gems  specifications  wrappers
```

Sometimes (almost I usually do) run your project with bundle --path bundle/vendor

That creates a folder bundle/vendor where it will store your gems and doesn't store doc (that makes bundler much faster than gem install)